# Vertical scroll on mobile - hammer.js element in page

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser, hammer.js

There are a million similar questions but I can't find an answer that works for me.

Here is the situation:

I have an HTML page, and within that page is an element that I am using hammer.js on.

Need to be able to scroll like this:
[image]
--->
[image]

While also being able to pinch-to-zoom (and subsequently pan on that zoomed element) on the seating chart element above.

The element itself works perfectly. I'm using `doubletap`, `pinch`, `pinchend`, `pan`, and `panend` on it.

Now, in the event that the element is totally zoomed out (I'm keeping track of the scale for this reason), I would like the entire page to scroll when using it on a mobile browser (aka the finger will be dragging the page up).

I have tried almost everything under the sun at this point. I can't seem to get it to manually scroll to a specific position (I have tried setting `window.scrollTop` and using `window.scrollTo()` with no results).

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'll worship you and your family for the next...say....13 days. Heck, maybe even 14.

**TL;DR**
- Have we pinch zoomed on the element? If so, handle panning around that element with glee!
- Are we fully zoomed out / pinched out on the element? If so, mobile users should be able to scroll the page like normal!

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You may try `window.scrollTo` to "simulate" normal scroll. Like so:

```
var currentScroll = 0;
var currentScale  = 1; //"fully zoomed out" state

hammer.on("panstart", function (ev) {
  currentScroll = window.scrollY;
});

hammer.on("pan", function(ev) {
  if (currentScale == 1) {
    //abort pan and scroll window instead
    window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll + ev.deltaY * -1);
    return;
  }

  //do stuff with pan here...

});
```